# scroll top of a div on clicking an element

Tags: jquery

i want a div to scroll to its top position on clicking on an element like an image or a div.
html:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div style="background: red; width: 100%; float: left; height:900px;">df</div>
```

css:

```
.arrow{ width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both; background-color: #ccc; cursor: pointer;}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $(window).scroll(function(){

           $('.arrow').click(function(){

               $(this).next('div').animate({scrollTop:0},600);


           });

       });//end window scroll
 });
```

i tried removing the  `$(window).scroll(function(){}` in case it appeared only on scrolling,but no effect. i just want the red box to move at the topon clicking the arrow div. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is bad practice, your code binds the click function with every pixel the window scrolls.

Comment: but i tried it without the $(window).scroll(function(){}, but no effect

Comment: Must be an error somewhere else. Works perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/fZyHT/

Comment: even this fiddle is not working in my system/browser. i am using chrome v35

Comment: His fiddle works for me, do you have extensions that could be messing it up? Appending click to scroll is insanely bad, if a site has that I could scroll up and down several times and create tens of thousands of click events, and site will eventually crash on my browser because it has an insane amount of events tied to 1 element. I highly recommend removing that .scroll()

Comment: @viion, you are right, but i remved the scroll() and still no effect, and the fiddle is really not working for me,i tried in chrome and firefox latest version

Comment: The fiddle works in chrome/FF/IE's latest versions under Win7. Try disabling addons/reverting to default settings if changed

Comment: @user3450590 Just curious, have you resized the box so the div actually scrolls? There isn't much text, so on my screen when I had browser maximised, it would seem to not work, as the content didn't fill the div enough to result in it scrolling, so I resized the html column very small so the scroll bar appeared, and then clicking the gray box would make it scroll up. Other than that, I'm not sure, it works here !

Comment: i am afraid you got it all wrong, i dont want the top content of red area to scroll on top, rather  want the red area itself to go on top when i click the arrow div